# Is a drawing drawn by a user considered user-generated content?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-generated-content

I'm working on an app which lets the user draw drawings and share to their facebook feed, and I'm wondering whether uploading the image to the staging-resources and using it is allowed? Because the website states that only camera-created photos are considered user-generated content, although this is drawn by the user, and is not considered app-generated.

Also, if it is possible to use that, can I somehow use it for feed posting instead of object/action posting?

I've used these links as references:
[Using the Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#creatingapp),
[Publish to Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/)

Thanks in advance for any help,

Tamper